# How to add a qip file to a Quartus project generated from a Makefile

Tags: fpga, intel-fpga, quartus

I like to have the project file untouched unless I make an active decision to add something, so I create the project file using make.

The first instance of the project file is created by quartus_map and I can later add pin declarations etc using quartus_sh.

But I have not found a good way to add an IP block, qip-file, to the project in time since quartus_map need all files to be available.

How can I solve this?

I'm currently using:

```
quartus_map project_name --analysis_and_elaboration --family=... -f sourcefiles.args
```

It will not help to add it in the list of source files...